# can't link external css when bootstrap is linked

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to link my external `css` file but it's not running when I'm linking bootstrap.
It gets linked when I comment out the bootstrap link.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>document</title>
  <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  it's not working.
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should link bootstrap above your own css files

css is cascading so the lower file is more important and can rewrite the upper ones

use  !important if replacing your link tags didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Some items require `!important` to be placed with them in order to over-ride Bootstrap commands.

I can't honestly remember you whether the `background` or `font-size` commands on your `body` element requires it or not but I've used it below as an example.

Add the same thing to any of your custom CSS commands that don't seem to be working.

```
body {
  background-color: black !important;
  font-size: 200px !important;
}
```

Comment: it was good when i placed the css link below bootstrap.